# Ubuntu 18 libreoffice not dragging to sides

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I can't drag and dock libreoffice documents to the sides. It worked for a couple of days, but now it only docks on the top and maximizes. So I have to manually adjust my windows in order to see two libreoffice windos beside one another. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Still works for me. Logging out then in might solve the issue. Do the hotkeys, Super+up left or right still work?

Comment: It works for all other windows, except for libreoffice even though it did work at first but stopped after a couple of days. Can I have inadvertently cancelled some function?

Comment: Do the hotkeys, Super+up left or right still work?

Comment: Yup, they do. The problem is only with Libreoffice.  Only working combination with Libreoffice is Super+up.

Comment: A coarse trick that tends to solve LO issues is to remove the user configuration folder. This way, LO is reset to factory default settings. This may  solve this issue.

Comment: It seems to be a common problem with a couple of programs. QGIS has the same problem, the only possible combination is Super+up. Super+left and super+right do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I track down that issue occurs with installed ***libreoffice-gtk3*** package. Remove this package and libreoffice windows should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a fundamental solution, while LibreOffice is starting up, you may be able to move the window by quickly entering Super + left (right).
@LibreOffice 6.0.6.2, Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Indeed, it is a short window of time. And it makes previously open libreoffice windows to work as well.